# Activity being recreated even after setting launchMode="singleTop"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I was implementing OAuth for Fitbit using a custom scheme and for that I require the instance of the calling `Activity` to be used from the top of stack after the user logs-in in the default browser and is redirected to the CALLBACK URL. Instead of `onNewIntent()` being called, the `Activity` is just recreated which is not what I require.

```
<activity
        android:name=".AppsAndDevicesActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="snbr" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I'm opening the browser from a Fragment using the following code:

```
String url = Fitbit.buildAuthenticationURL();
Log.d("URL", url);
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
this.getActivity().startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use launchmode as **singleTask** because:

**singleTask:**

The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of the new task. **However, if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance.** Only one instance of the activity can exist at a time.

Note: Although the activity starts in a new task, the Back button still returns the user to the previous activity.

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried that and it works pretty much as required but why isn't the method in the question working. It seems to work for other people. Also, does `singleTask` necessarily start a new task? If yes, what are the side-effects of a new task being created?